# How to read into a running processus in c?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, process, portable-executable

Hi how to read into a  processus and how to use IMAGE_FILE_HEADER to read the pe header in this processus, 
thanks for replies:) sorry for my english i'm french .
I try but i fail to code a program which made this so i search how to code this , by the way i don't know where extract the code in an other processus and use  IMAGE_FILE_HEADER to read the pe header

thanks for replie search an help :)

```
image_file_header file;
//how to use this from a handle or a hmodule ?
```

Comment: this looks like a window format of the executable file which you should be able to read from disk: https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/2-malware-researchers-handbook-demystifying-pe-file/#gref

Comment: okay but that isn't help ,i don't how i read the pe header of an application which run

Comment: from the image file? you can get it as `argv[0]`.

Comment: mmmmh i want fork a remote process to get a file and reverse it to  break security of a server like a telnet or ssh authentication to get a session . What is a image file ?? is a process or a thread ?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [PEB](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEB-Process-Environment-Block) from the remote process with [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess) and 'ProcessBasicInformation'. Then you can read the 'lpImageBaseAddress' from the [PEB](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEB-Process-Environment-Block).
And from that address you can read the entire PE Header of the base executable (Usually the first 1024 bytes) from the process memory.

Comment: can i have a example source code in c ? i'm a beginer